# How to inflate a default android widget?

Tags: android, kotlin

In other words,`LayoutInflater.from(...).inflate()` require either a *XmlPullParser* or an *Resource Locator*. How can I instruct it to inflate a default View such as a *TextView* or a *Button* ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out that on runtime, the instantiation of a *View* object already inflates it.

In the end, the whole expression: 
`LayoutInflater.from(...).inflate()`
can be replaced with the widget itself:
`TextView(parent.context)` (for a TextView)